# Combining Mysql sub queries

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table of products. to perform a search am using 3 different queries to get most matching results. but am getting few bummers eg pagination thus the need to combine my 3 queries to one and still give same results.

here are my queries and an explanation of what each does

**Query 1: this query gets exact matches to the search string**

```
SELECT *, 
       MATCH (product_name) AGAINST ('k' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as distance, 
       MATCH (product_description) AGAINST ('k' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as distance2 
FROM  products 
INNER JOIN shops ON shops.shop_id = products.shop_id 
WHERE MATCH  (product_name) AGAINST ('k') 
   OR MATCH (product_description) AGAINST ('k') 
ORDER BY distance DESC, distance2 DESC 
LIMIT 0, 9;
```

**Query 2: this query gets all results where the search string is part of string minus the results of query one then adds results to array**

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN shops ON shops.shop_id = products.shop_id 
WHERE product_name LIKE '%k%' 
ORDER BY INSTR(product_name,'k'), product_name 
LIMIT 0, 9;
```

**Query 3: this query gets closest match to the search string minus results of query 1 and query 2 adds results to array**

```
SELECT *, 
      fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_name ) as distance, 
      fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_description ) as distance2 
 FROM products 
 INNER JOIN shops ON shops.shop_id = products.shop_id 
 WHERE (fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_name ) < 3 
    OR fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_description ) < 3) 
   AND product_id NOT IN ('pr933j4', 'Posr49il', 'p4021dd') 
 order by distance ASC, distance2 ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 9;
```

i cant figure out how to combine this three queries to one any suggestions to the right direction are highly appreciated. 
**NOTE 'k' is the string being searched**

Comment: HINT: `UNION` or `JOIN` I dont see what is the problem here

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza am actually trying out UNION . how would a join work?

Comment: @dannjoroge It wouldn't, `UNION` is the right thing.

Comment: You'll need to add the distance columns to the second query, since all queries in a union have to have the same column.

Comment: Again you have to explain what is the problem. Look like you try to get 10 rows from first query and if not enough rows then some from query 2 and 3 until you achive 10? But again show us some example with data so we can understand.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. UNION seems to work. will post a solution once i get one that does exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

UNION worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM 
 ( (SELECT j1.* FROM products AS j1 LEFT JOIN shops AS z1 ON z1.shop_id = 
    j1.shop_id WHERE MATCH (product_name) AGAINST ('k') OR MATCH 
    (product_description) AGAINST ('k') ORDER BY MATCH (product_name) 
    AGAINST ('k' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC, MATCH (product_description) AGAINST 
    ('k' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC ) s1)

UNION 

SELECT * FROM 
 ( ( SELECT j2.* FROM products AS j2 LEFT JOIN shops AS z2 ON 
    z2.shop_id = j2.shop_id WHERE product_name LIKE '%k%' ORDER BY 
    INSTR(product_name,'k'), product_name ) s2)

UNION 

SELECT * FROM 
 ( ( SELECT j3.* FROM products as j3 LEFT JOIN shops as z3 ON z3.shop_id = 
    j3.shop_id WHERE (fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_name ) < 3 OR 
    fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_description ) < 3) AND product_id NOT IN 
    ('pr933j4', 'Posr49il', 'p4021dd') order by fuzzy_substring( 'k', 
    product_name ) ASC, fuzzy_substring( 'k', product_description ) ASC ) 
    s3)
```